How Do I Change The View To Orbit Around A Changing Pivot Point?
I wanted to know where I am going wrong with my code. I'm trying to replicate a similar view to how Old School Runescape works, except instead of 3D objects I am using sprite stacked objects to fake a 3D environment.
The way I understand this working is that when the player moves in the actual world the new pivot point should be based on the tile the player is currently in and objects with their defined positions should adjust to the current pivot point.


import math

import pygame
from math import *
from pygame import Vector2

import shader


class DrawingObject:
    def __init__(self, mainWindow, modMapSurface, mapCenter, worldPosX, worldPosY, playerPosX, playerPosY, camRotAngle, camTiltAngle):
        self.mainWindow = mainWindow
        self.modMapSurface = modMapSurface
        self.mapCenter = mapCenter
        self.worldPosX = worldPosX
        self.worldPosY = worldPosY
        self.playerPosX = playerPosX
        self.playerPosY = playerPosY
        self.camRotAngle = camRotAngle
        self.camTiltAngle = camTiltAngle

        DrawingObject.draw(self)

    def draw(self):
        objectImageList = []
        imageScale = 4

        # worldPosX, worldPosY, imageFilePath
        worldObjectList =\
        [
            [512, 512, "Graphics\\person.png"],
            [640, 512, "Graphics\\testBlock3.png"],
            [768, 512, "Graphics\\testBlock2.png"],
            [896, 896, "Graphics\\frog.png"],
        ]

        for i in range(len(worldObjectList)):
            currentObjectImage = pygame.image.load(worldObjectList[i][2]).convert_alpha()

            # Scale
            imageWdith =  currentObjectImage.get_width()
            imageHeight = currentObjectImage.get_height()
            scaledWidth = imageWdith * imageScale
            scaledHeight = imageHeight * imageScale

            currentObjectImage = pygame.transform.scale(currentObjectImage, (scaledWidth, scaledHeight))

            cellCount = currentObjectImage.get_width() // currentObjectImage.get_height()
            print(cellCount)

            objPosX = worldObjectList[i][0]
            objPosY = worldObjectList[i][1]

            for i in range(cellCount):
                imageObjectRect = pygame.Rect(scaledHeight * i, 0, scaledHeight, scaledHeight)
                objectImageList.append(imageObjectRect)

                objectSurface = pygame.Surface((scaledHeight, scaledHeight))
                objectSurface.blit(currentObjectImage, (0, 0), objectImageList[i])

                objectSurface.set_colorkey([0, 0, 0])

                # Call shader function
                #shader.shader(objectSurface, cellCount, i)

                objectSurfaceRot = pygame.transform.rotate(objectSurface, self.camRotAngle)
                objectRotWidth, objectRotHeight = objectSurfaceRot.get_size()

                # Object drawing
                modObjectSurface = pygame.transform.scale(objectSurfaceRot, (objectRotWidth, objectRotHeight / 90 * self.camTiltAngle))
                #objectCenter = modObjectSurface.get_rect(center=(originPosX + self.worldPosX, originPosY + self.worldPosY - imageScale * i))

                # Orbit
                #distance = math.sqrt((objPosX - objPosY)**2 + (self.worldPosX - self.worldPosY)**2)
                distance = Vector2(self.worldPosX, self.worldPosY).distance_to((objPosX, objPosY))
                pivot = (self.worldPosX, self.worldPosY - imageScale * i)
                orbOffset = Vector2()

                # Need distance from player to obj
                orbOffset.from_polar((distance, -self.camRotAngle))
                newPos = pivot + orbOffset
                orbRect = modObjectSurface.get_rect(center = newPos)

                self.mainWindow.blit(modObjectSurface, orbRect)

The issues right now are that the world objects to not seem to adjust to the world position, and the objects also "bounce" up and down when I rotate the camera. The lower the tilt of the camera the more noticeable the 'bounce" is. I tried various ways to calculate the distance from the world object to the player's world position, but the movement is still very off.
